# Starting a Node Startup Help

Tags: stake-pool

The team and i have decided to start a node in the Cardano ecosystem.
we have mac book pro with m1 chip that meets the requirement and ubuntu installed but having problems with rufus for some reason can anyone help me get this going.
any info will be appreciated im sure in some way or another

Comment: Please try to put some information regarding the specific error so we can help you out

Answer (score 2):

If this is still a topic for you may look at the cnTools guide and framework to setup your Stakepool Relays and BlockProducer

https://cardano-community.github.io/guild-operators/